# Unknown Property Error on custom VisualForce page

Tags: visualforce, controller

Page:

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" controller="ComposeEmailController">
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bootstrap, 'sf-bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bootstrap, 'sf-bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')}"/>

<apex:form styleClass="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <apex:selectList value="{!fromAddresses}" multiselect="false">
        </apex:selectList>
    </div>
</apex:form>
```

Controller:

```
public class ComposeEmailController {

String fromAddress{get; set;}
Case memberCase {get; set;}
Account account {get; set;}
Contact contact {get; set;}
public List<From_Email_Address__c> fromAddresses;


    public ComposeEmailController() {
        fromAddresses = [Select Id, Name, From_Address__c FROM From_Email_Address__c ORDER BY Name];
    }
}
```

Error:

> Unknown property 'ComposeEmailController.fromAddresses'  (Line: 1, Column: -1)

Comment: have a get;set; for fromAddresses

Comment: I tried that and am still getting the same error

Comment: Thats really strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue

```
public List<From_Email_Address__c> fromAddresses;
```

This must be of type string not From_Email_Address__c

Updated controller:

```
public class ComposeEmailController {

String fromAddress{get; set;}
Case memberCase {get; set;}
Account account {get; set;}
Contact contact {get; set;}
public List<String> fromAddresses {get; set;}
private Map<String, String> fromAddressesMap;


    public ComposeEmailController() {
        List<From_Email_Address__c> addresses = [Select Id, Name, From_Address__c FROM From_Email_Address__c ORDER BY Name];
        System.debug('I have this many addresses: ' + addresses.size());
        fromAddresses = new List<String>();
        fromAddressesMap = new Map<String, String>();
        for(From_Email_Address__c email : addresses){
            fromAddresses.add(email.Name);
            fromAddressesMap.put(email.Name, email.From_Address__c);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because:

- You have not defined property named `fromAddresses` in Controller
- The property is not public
- you have not defined {get; set;}

Comment: I've added get and set and am still receiving the error

Comment: Can you post the updated code?

Comment: Found the issue. The list needs to be of type string not sObject

Comment: Good, that you got it resolved.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @prady answer, there's another insidious reason you can get an Unknown Property error on a Visualforce page (although not applicable to OP) and I'm adding it here for posterity

**Controller**

```
public class MyController {
  public String foo {get; private set;}
}
```

**VF Page MyVfPage**

```
<apex:page controller='MyController">

    ..some markup1..

    <apex:outputText value="{!foo'}/>

    .. some markup2...

<apex:page>
```

- where `some markup1` includes another `<apex:page>`
- where `some markup2` includes a `</apex:page>`
- yields `Unknown property foo in MyVfPage`

That is, your reference to the controller property is contained inside an inner `apex:page`.  Because the inner `apex:page` is not bound to a controller, the VF compiler can't find the property. Of course, you shouldn't be using nested `apex:pages` anyway so this is most likely a self-inflicted wound when you meant to use `apex:pageBlock`